# Can I generate static HTML/CSS to be used in email templates from a simple site containing dynamic parts with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html-email, mailchimp, static-generator

I need to retrieve information from an API say every week where I just click on a button and I use js to retrieve the required information and display that in the DOM accordingly. However, I would like to use this newly generated site and copy that current info to be sent off in newsletters.

What's the best way to generate static HTML/CSS templates that can be used in emails since I cant use scripts dynamically in email HTML ideally. More conveniently, the emails would be sent off using Mailchimp so if there was a way to just have those dynamic parts auto-filled, that would be lovely. However, I am happy to simply copy and paste the static HTML/CSS and paste in mailchimp manually.

What's the best way to go about this please?

Comment: You can do all of that in Mailchimp. Read the Mailchimp documentation. It explains how to add dynamic content to a template.

Comment: You can also create/design the template in Mailchimp.

Comment: Thank you @Cully, I guess more info would shed more light. The dynamic info here are woocommerce products. I would like to retrieve say the latest 6 products from a certain woocommerce category and send that weekly (the products change frequently). Is this something that the dynamic section of mailchimp templates can handle? This was what I found relating to dynamic content on mailchimp - https://mailchimp.com/help/about-dynamic-content/

Comment: What you need to check out then is a Woocommerce Mailchimp plugin or integration, such as https://mailchimp.com/integrations/woocommerce/

Comment: Yes, you could do that with dynamic content. Though I'm not sure to what degree you can set unique content for specific users in your mailing list with Mailchimp. I think what you want is a "transactional email service". That would let you send emails to specific addresses with specific content.

Comment: @Nathan please correct me if im wrong, I believe the mailchimp woocommerce plugin works for order emails, abandoned cart recovery etc. What I want to do is to send normal email campaigns as you would with mailchimp where these emails would have blocks of products. The products would be from certain categories on the website but at the moment, that info is copied manually from woocommerce to mailchimp for each product. I would like to automate this where the product info is automatically set up in the emails without having to copy it manually each time. Is this something the plugin can do pls?

Comment: @Cully please do you know if this is possible with the mailchimp dynamic content? Where mailchimp retrieves product information automatically from woocommerce and I can display product blocks as required in a regular email template to be sent out to a list (not the automated emails sent to reward customers or win back old customers. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Temak See this page, which I think is what you're asking for? https://mailchimp.com/features/personalized-product-recommendations/

Comment: Hi @Nathan thank you for the response. I have checked that out and it works to a certain degree. However, what I require needs a bit more customization. I would like the set up to work as a regular campaign and not under the ecommerce automation. I would also like the ability to retrieve existing categories from woocommerce as well as the product description being retrieved just as the name and price are. Do you know any solution that works this way please? I am also open to solutions outside of Mailchimp that can have this workflow as described. I appreciate all the help.